# The named parameter 'horizontalTitleGap' isn't defined (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters

My flutter version is
environment:
sdk:  ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
There is a problem in my code, the named parameter `horizontalTitleGap` of `ListTitle` widget isn't defined.
Where I use `horizontalTitleGap` this error shows up, anyone can help me solve this problem of `horizontalTitleGap`?

```dart
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
    import 'package:jaitunproject/providers/auth_provider.dart';
    import 'package:jaitunproject/providers/locaiton_provider.dart';
    import 'package:jaitunproject/screen/profile_update_screen.dart';
    import 'package:jaitunproject/screen/welcome_screen.dart';
    import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    import 'map_screen.dart';
    
    class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      static const String id = 'profile-screen';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var userDetails = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
        var locationData = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context);
        User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        userDetails.getUserDetails();
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            title: Text(
              'Multi-Vendor Store',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'MY ACCOUNT',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 40,
                                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'M',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        userDetails.snapshot.data()['firstName'] !=
                                                null
                                            ? '${userDetails.snapshot.data()['firstName']} ${userDetails.snapshot.data()['lastName']}'
                                            : 'Update Your Name',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      if (userDetails.snapshot.data()['email'] !=
                                          null) //other wise hide
                                        Text(
                                          '${userDetails.snapshot.data()['email']}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      Text(
                                        user.phoneNumber,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            if (userDetails.snapshot != null)
                              ListTile(
                                tileColor: Colors.white,
                                leading: Icon(
                                  Icons.location_on,
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                ),
                                title:
                                    Text(userDetails.snapshot.data()['location']),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  userDetails.snapshot.data()['address'],
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                ),
                                trailing: SizedBox(
                                  width: 80,
                                  child: OutlineButton(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Change',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      EasyLoading.show(status: 'Please wait...');
                                      locationData
                                          .getCurrentPosition()
                                          .then((value) {
                                        if (value != null) {
                                          EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                          pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                                            context,
                                            settings:
                                                RouteSettings(name: MapScreen.id),
                                            screen: MapScreen(),
                                            withNavBar: false,
                                            pageTransitionAnimation:
                                                PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                          print('Permission not allowed');
                                        }
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      right: 10.0,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.edit_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                            context,
                            settings: RouteSettings(name: UpdateProfile.id),
                            screen: UpdateProfile(),
                            withNavBar: false,
                            pageTransitionAnimation:
                                PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                  title: Text('My Orders'),
                  horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.comment_outlined),
                  title: Text('My Ratings & Reviews'),
                  horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
                  title: Text('Notifications'),
                  horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
                  title: Text('Logout'),
                  horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                  onTap: () {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                      context,
                      settings: RouteSettings(name: WelcomeScreen.id),
                      screen: WelcomeScreen(),
                      withNavBar: false,
                      // since navigating to outside made it false 'cause nothing to be accessed without login
                      pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: try `flutter clean`, restart the IDE. Does it resolve now?

Comment: Yeah, I try right now but not happened at all.

Comment: try to upgrade the flutter, also check the source code of it.

Comment: I try to upgrade but not work it, same error showings